# Target application crashes when using ReadProcessMemory

Tags: memory, exception

I have an interesting application that seems to crash whenever a particular region of memory is read using [ReadProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx). I know it's not doing anything special with RPM because:

1. Injecting a DLL to read that region of memory directly also causes a crash.
2. Scanning regions with applications like [CheatEngine](http://www.cheatengine.org/) also causes a crash.

It's also not a guard region or a region with special protection flags. It's just a private R+W region.

At first I thought they were installing hardware data breakpoints like those described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28071/Toggle-hardware-data-read-execute-breakpoints-prog), but after checking the debug registers of all threads and seeing that they were all zero made me conclude that another technique is used.

I suspect that they are somehow raising an exception whenever that piece of memory is read. I'm looking to understand what they're doing and how to detect it, or at the very least, make RPM not crash the application.

P.S. I cannot attach a debugger to this application, and the executable is encrypted, but I do know that various TLS callbacks are used along with VEH exception handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, it would appear that we have an answer to this. And it's a lot simpler than I thought, and actually pretty cool.

Basically, they allocate some pages with no physical backing until the page is accessed. This means that any access whatsoever (even in kernel mode) will validate the page, thus allowing the application to see that the page has been validated and promptly crash the game.

To avoid this, you can use [QueryWorkingSetEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684949(v=vs.85).aspx) or [NtQueryVirtualMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn957452(v=vs.85).aspx) and if the "valid" property of the returned structure is zero, then you probably shouldn't be reading that page.

I can't say for certain that this is the correct answer, but it fits my analysis. If anybody has more information on this technique, specifically how to implement it with something like [VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx), I would love to learn more.

P.S. The application doesn't appear to have any kernel mode access whatsoever, it's just a regular user mode application.

**EDIT:** Sample C++ implementation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/dkrutsko/d6118638b0ef711b30bfcfe5b083d067).

Comment: let me guess, the game you were trying to RPM is either Overwatch or Wow from Blizzard? This technique has been discussed in many game cheating websites. And yes, this is the way they detect RPM

Answer (score 1):

Check if attaching windbg in [non-invasive mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552274(v=vs.85).aspx) works. If yes, [check the page permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666721/windbg-how-to-check-memory-segment-permission) of the target address range.

Comment: Yep, I tried that before, and it still crashed. But I checked the page permission externally and it came up as 0x4 (PAGE_READWRITE).

Comment: @Dave: well, in that case I can only suggest checking what exactly happens using a kernel debugger.

Comment: Yep I think I might end up doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any kernel mode anti-debug? The ReadProcessMemory is using KeAttachProcess. Maybe there's an inline hook that stops you.

Using ARK tools like PCHunter can search hooks in your system easily.

And I don't think that the application can detect RPM in user mode. In fact, to detect RPM, either hooking NtReadVirtualMemory or hooking the system page fault handler is need. What's more, even if the page is protected with PAGE_NO_ACCESS, the application shouldn't crash.

So I suspect that there is kernel mode hooking.

Comment: I'll have to give it a try, but I want to emphesize that it's not only RPM, reading the memory directly through code injection crashes the application as well. Maybe there is some VEH magic going on but I have to read up on it.

Comment: @Dave Are you sure that the reading memory operation makes the  application crash? Maybe it crashes when you inject, and that's very usual.

Comment: @Dave And what's crash information? You can upload a dump of that program.

Comment: I conducted a simple test. I injected a DLL and scanned a regular region. Then I detached the DLL. I attached it again to scan another region I suspected was going to crash and it did, about 4600 bytes in.

The program has a built in crash mailer. It's not so much that it crashes but just hangs until you terminate it.

Comment: have you asked in other communities? I googled it and You are trying to deal with Overwatch app.Since it is a game client, I strongly suspect there is kernel mode protect

Comment: @Dave and the VEH handlers are called only if there are exceptions. And it might set hardware bp. But you've said that the debug register are zero. So I don't think the VEH causes the crash. Also the RPM happens in your process instead of target process.

Comment: Yep, it's Overwatch. At this point I'm less interested in hacking it and more just trying to understand all the tricks they're doing. Sadly, my reversing skills are lacking, but I'm trying to keep up. You're probably right about the Kernel mode protection though. I should mention that it can't be ran in limited user mode and I had it crash once when running as a standard user.

Comment: @Dave Good luck.You can grab some information from tuts4you. But you need a good Windows kernel understanding.

Comment: @Dave As the usermode anti debug technology is widely known and kernel internals are revealed, a lot of commercial software started to use driver anti-debug.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look! I'm probably going to pick up a copy of Windows Internals as it was recommended to me by a good friend. Hopefully it'll bring me up to speed a bit more.

Comment: @Dave Personally,Windows Internals doesn't help much. It's just like a dictionary of Windows kernel. I have read that two thick books. If you are not going to develop a Windows driver, it's meaningless.

Comment: Any good books you might recommend?

Comment: @Dave Like Software Debugging. It is about usermode software. As for kernel, you can use Windows Internals as an dictionary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40312/discussion-between-yunchao-guan-and-dave).

Comment: any chance you can share the application? you are describing pretty interesting case.

Comment: @ph0sec Original question here:   http://www.ownedcore.com/forums/fps/overwatch-exploits-hacks/557169-overwatch-crashes-readprocessmemory.html    Kernel mode protect is in fashion.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualProtect or WriteProcessMemory are affected by this

because windows checks up the Vad Table with 
with a internal function called "MiCheckForConflictingNode"
windows reacts to 0x00200000 what is 2 = VVadImageMap = 2
to value 0x00400000 what is in VadTypeVadWriteWatch = 4 
to value 0x0008000 this flag is "NoChange" yes (1) or no (0) either contains 0 or 1

KeAttachProcess also calls a trigger im uncertain if its a flag or a function that got set

the trigger from the target is made to delay executed
it then read out that information that got left from KeAttachProcess

after this the target prints a error but its only a trigger

to avoid this do not use that functions or either emulate them so they dont call triggers or flags
there other ways too

microsoft gives a .txt file what includes text that is pure scam and talks like 10 pages about that microsoft is protecting those companys

and saying something like "stack error" what is not the case its just scamming and trolling

also i figured out that this part got added to windows with over a so called "security update" what is rather about the take the users away the rights from his own computer

thats why i never liked windbg it has a tons of dependencies

as you can see this problem here